# Push Notifications with Airship on Apple iOS certificate reject

Tags: apple-push-notifications, certificate, urbanairship.com

I want to use Urban Airship Push Notifications in my Titanium application.So i followed this guide exactly http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Push+Notifications#.

Problem is that at final point when I'm submitting my *.p12 certificate I'm getting rejection by Apple (look at print screen image) 
http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/8645/pscreen.png

I'm new in iPhone development and all the Certificates they require.

If someone could please tell what am I doing wrong... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer,but I already resolved this.
I just recreated my whole keychain with brand new development certificates,followed the guide step by step to make sure I'm not missing anything.I've also used Titanium Developer instead of Titanium Studio itself.And magically it just worked :)

So for all who will encounter similar problem,just follow the guide,it's 100% working.

Answer (score 2):

I Think you submitted the Distribution Certificate for Urban Airship Push Notifications Trail. It must accept the Development Certificates until you buy that.